# Conditional exit(0); in applicationDidEnterBackground?

Tags: iphone, xcode, exit

Is it ok to use exit(0); like this?

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     if (UserDontWantItRunInBackground) {
        exit(0);
     }
}
```

Will Apple approve it?

Comment: This is a question for Apple's support team. We can't answer it.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Apple don't like you to use `exit()` at all.

Indeed, from Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1):

```
Don’t Quit Programmatically

Never quit an iOS app programmatically because people tend to interpret this as a crash.
```

As far as I can tell, although it might work exactly as you intend, there is a very good chance your app would be rejected.

Comment: +1 but not so certain about the certain reject.  It's certainly grounds to reject according to the docs, but I've found their enforcement on lot's of stuff disturbingly random.

Comment: changed it to "very good chance". =)

Comment: My app is working in background using lots of power. I kinda need user to choose if he wants it to work in background or not. Actually its not an actual quitting programmatically - user should press home button or lock-screen button.

Comment: In general, apple doesn't reject such behavior, but if you limit user experience (fast application switching with storing current state), you must understand why you did it. P.S. if your app use a lots of power in background(!), it's better to stop all app activities, without unloading app.

Comment: Well, there's one way to find out if they'll accept this particular instance....

Comment: Ok, I thought about turning off all activities, but can't figure out the right way to start running them after opening app from background mode. viewDidLoad is not called for some reasons...

Comment: and yes, i'm a noob, sorry.